# Homogenization, what it is in inequalities and how to utilize it to its fullest.

Tags: inequality, contest-math, problem-solving, a.m.-g.m.-inequality, rearrangement-inequality

I have just learnt about homogenization, however I don't really understand it and I can't really utilize it (https://artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php/Homogenization this is where I learnt about it). Could you please explain to me how to use it optimally? Moreover I found a question on IMO 2020, which I believe can be solved using homogenization. It goes as follows:

Let the real numbers $a, b, c, d$ be such that $a\ge b\ge c \ge d >0$ and $a+b+c+d=1$. Prove that:

$(a+2b+3c+4d)a^ab^bc^cd^d<1$

I attempted to solve it by saying that RHS is equal to $(a+b+c+d)^a$, but then I realized that this doesn't help and it doesn't homogenize the inequality either. Then I tried using AM-GM on LHS and getting something which can be homogenized, however I did not succeed there either. Could you please explain to me how to use homogenization optimally and how this question could be solved using it?

Comment: "I just learnt about homogeniezation" you could tell us which textbook you learnt from, or which online resource you used. Ideally a link to a page, or the book would be more helpful.

Comment: Ok sending the link now @TeresaLisbon

Comment: thank you for that, I have upvoted your question.

Comment: But I find this question impossible to homogenize, because it is usually used for *polynomial* inequalities, where it is possible to bring all terms to the same degree. However, the "degree" (if you can call it that here) actually varies with $a$, so I don't know how you will work this out. One way is to bound just the term $a^ab^bc^cd^d$ by some homogeneous polynomial in $a,b,c,d$, and then try homogeniezation. Note that you've picked a very difficult problem : it's an IMO problem! So it is not clear what to do at all in the starting.

Comment: Here's a thought : use Bernoulli's inequality (or any power-type inequality) to see if you can bound $a^ab^bc^cd^d$ by some polynomial in $a,b,c,d$? Probably deal with each of these terms separately?

Comment: @Teresa Lisbon  Bernoulli does not help here. I solved this problem, but organizers asked  not to discuss problems IMO 2020 until 24.00

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg 24.00? 24.00 which country's time? Sorry for posting it up then, I was not aware of this stipulation.

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg should I delete the post then? Or should I just leave it and I will receive responses after 24.00?

Comment: See here: https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h2277416

Comment: @Michael  No. Not need to delete. I want to post my solution. :)

Comment: Ok nice :). Wasn't aware of this regulation, but I am now, thank you

Comment: By the way @MichaelRozenberg, looking forward to seeing your solution to it :)

Comment: @Michael   Problems was posted on the official site. I posted my solution.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

By AM-GM $$\prod_{cyc}a^a\leq\sum_{cyc}a^2.$$
Thus, it's enough to prove that $$(a+b+c+d)^3>(a+2b+3c+4d)(a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2),$$
which is obvious after full expanding.

Comment: wow, that sure was neat Thanks a lot. How did you think of it though? How did you think of turning LHS into $(a+b+c+d)^3$?

Comment: @Michael  The first step it's a standard step to delete exponents by AM-GM: for any $\alpha_i>0$ such that $\alpha_1+\alpha_2+...+\alpha_n=1$ and $x_i>0$ we have: $\alpha_1x_1+...+\alpha_nx_n\geq x_1^{\alpha_1}...x_n^{\alpha_n}.$ The second step it's just homogenization, which you looked for.

Comment: wow understood fully now Mr. Rozenberg, if possible could I ask one more thing? Could you please send me a link which fully explains homogenization, and has a few examples as I really don't know how to use it?

Comment: I understand what you have done with homogenization, but I know that I would never have thought of that step

Comment: @Michael After using AM-GM we need to prove that $(a+2b+3c+4d)(a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2)<1.$ The degree of the left homogeneous polynomial is $3$, but the degree of the right homogeneous polynomial is $0$. Since $a+b+c+d=1$ we can make a degree of these polynomials are equal. It's a homogenization exactly. Now we can look on this inequality as on a homogeneous inequality of degree $3$ and we don't need a condition now. For this thing we always make a homogenization: to delete conditions. I have no a document about homogenization. But there is google...

Comment: Understood it fully now Mr. Rozenberg, thank you so much. Despite researching homogenization on google quite a few times, I never understood the concept fully, however, I believe that I now have, due to you. Thank you, have a good day

Comment: You are welcome, @Michael

Answer (score 3):

Note that $a+2b+3c+4d \leqslant a + 3(b+c+d).$ Using the weighted AM-GM, we have
$$a^2 + b^2 + c^2 + d^2 \geqslant a^ab^bc^cd^d.$$
We need to show that
$$\left[a+3(b+c+d)\right](a^2 + b^2 + c^2 + d^2) \leqslant (a+b+c+d)^3,$$
equivalent to
$$2(b+c+d)\left[a(b+c+d)-b^2-c^2-d^2\right]+2(a+b+c+d)(bc+cd+db) \geqslant 0.$$
Which is true because $a \geqslant b \geqslant c \geqslant d.$

Answer (score 1):

A way to work with homogeneizing an inequality is to substituite every variable $x$ by $x/R$.

This way we have $a/R+b/R+c/R+d/R=1$ and

$(a/R+2b/R+3c/R+4d/R)(a/R)^{a/R}(b/R)^{b/R}(c/R)^{c/R}(d/R)^{d/R}<1$

Or, by substituting $R=a+b+c+d$,

$(a+2b+3c+4d)/(a+b+c+d)(a/R)^{a/R}(b/R)^{b/R}(c/R)^{c/R}(d/R)^{d/R}<1$

$(a+2b+3c+4d)/(a+b+c+d) \cdot ((a/R)^{a}(b/R)^{b}(c/R)^{c}(d/R)^{d})^{1/R}<1$

$(a+2b+3c+4d)/(a+b+c+d) \cdot \left(\frac{a^ab^bc^cd^d}{R^{a+b+c+d}}\right)^{1/R}<1$

$(a+2b+3c+4d)/(a+b+c+d) \cdot \left(\frac{(a^ab^bc^cd^d)^{1/R}}{R}\right)<1$

$(a+2b+3c+4d)\cdot (a^ab^bc^cd^d)^{1/(a+b+c+d)}<(a+b+c+d)^2$

And well, man, this is ugly! But it is homogeneous as desired.

Anyway, I think there is only one possible solution for this: use

$(a^ab^bc^cd^d)^{1/(a+b+c+d)} \leq \frac{aa+bb+cc+dd}{a+b+c+d} $

and prove that

$(a+2b+3c+4d)\cdot (a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2)<(a+b+c+d)^3$.

You can use the infamous Bulldozer Technique: substitutions!

\begin{align}
a &= A+B+C+D \\
b &= B+C+D \\
c &= C+D \\
d &= D
\end{align}

where $A,B,C \geq 0,D > 0$. Expanding everything, the inequality becomes obvious. Indeed, dehomogeneizing it by putting $D=1$, we have the inequality as being the same as

$9 C^{3} + C^{2} \left(12 A + 21 B + 42\right) + C \left(A^{2} + 14 A B + 34 A + 12 B^{2} + 62 B + 60\right) + A^{2} B + 4 A B^{2} + 18 A B + 24 A + 2 B^{3} + 16 B^{2} + 44 B +  24 > 0$

In certain sense it implies the inequality is way loose.

(Yes, I used [Sympy Gamma](https://gamma.sympy.org/) here!)

Answer (score 1):

clean solution without any expansion

As others have noted, it is sufficient to show $$(a+b+c+d)^3 \ge (a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2)(a+2b+3c+4d)$$
write it as $$\dfrac{(a+b+c+d)^2}{a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2} \ge \dfrac{a+2b+3c+4d}{a+b+c+d}$$
subtracting 1,
$$\dfrac{2\sum_{sym} ab}{\sum a^2}\ge \dfrac{b+2c+3d}{a+b+c+d}$$
equivalent to
$$ \dfrac{2\sum_{sym} ab}{b+2c+3d}\ge \dfrac{a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2}{a+b+c+d}$$
which is true bcoz
$$ \dfrac{2\sum_{sym} ab}{b+2c+3d}\ge a \ge \dfrac{a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2}{a+b+c+d}$$

Comment: Your last inequality on the left hand side (2∑cyc  ab / (b+2c+3d) ≥a) is wrong. You can check with a = 0.7, b=c=d=0.1

Comment: I meant $sym$ instead of $cyc$ sorry for that

Comment: It is nice. (+1)