# Prove that $(a + 2b + 3c + 4d)a^a b^b c^c d^d < 1 $.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

This is question from yesterday's IMO.

> The real numbers $a$, $b$, $c$, $d$ are such that $a ≥ b ≥ c ≥ d > 0$ and $a + b + c + d = 1$.
>
> Prove that
> $$(a + 2b + 3c + 4d)a^a b^b c^cd^d < 1$$

Comment: I suggest that you tell us what you've attempted first

Comment: See here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3836027

Answer (score 0):

Using weighted AM-GM inequality, detail below

https://mathgarage.wordpress.com/2020/09/25/imo-2020-problem-2-is-so-easy-that-i-can-do-it-without-peeking-at-the-solution/